# Why can't I load text files in GNU Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

The following code lines were written by my instructor. Those seemed to be working well in his PC.

But, I couldn't load files as he did in the lab.

```
load iris2.txt
iris2(:,1)=2;
load iris3.txt
iris3(:,1)=3;

ts=iris(48:53, :);

for i=1:rows(ts)
    clslnn(ts, ts(i, 2:end)+0.3)
end
```

I tried this in my pc as well,

```
>> load train.txt
error: load: unable to determine file format of 'train.txt'
>> load 'train.txt'
error: load: unable to determine file format of 'train.txt'
>>
```

So, what could be the issue here?

Comment: train.txt is different from iris2.txt... Perhaps we could tell you (or you would even see it yourself) if you would upload train.txt and provide a link or insert some lines. Are you both using GNU/Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

.txt files with strings(even if partly exist) cannot be loaded in that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the format used in a txt file the following way:

```
[a,b,c,d] = textread("iris2.txt", "%f %f %f %f", \
 'delimiter', '\t', "endofline", "\n", 'headerlines', 1);
X = [a, b, c, d];
disp(X);
```

Each column of values will be saved in the corresponding vectors a,b,c,d. `X=[a,b,c,d];` will merge them into single matrix.